# How to name a property using a reserved keyword in OpenApi/Swagger/YAML

Tags: yaml, swagger, openapi, surveyjs

Is there any way to name a custom property 'type', given that there already exists a special 'type' property which is a reserved keyword.

```
components:  
  schemas:  
  element:  
  type: object 
  properties:  
    name:  
      type: string  #type here is the keyword
    type: #type here is the actual name of the property!
      type: string
        enum:
          - radiogroup
          - checkbox
```

The back-end system which produces the JSON messages cannot be modified to rename the property.
Thanks.

Comment: ps. sample of original json data is:elements:
    [
      { type: "radiogroup",
      name: "DentalQuestion2" }
      ,
      { type: "checkbox",
      name: "DentalQuesiton3" }
      ]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Reserved keywords can be used as property/parameter names in all OpenAPI versions.

The only issue with your example is that YAML indentation is off, other than that your object and property definitions are perfectly valid.

```yaml
components:  
  schemas:  
    element:  
      type: object 
      properties:  
        name:  
          type: string
        type:   # <----- yes, property name can be "type"
          type: string
          enum:
            - radiogroup
            - checkbox
```

Comment: when java code is generated, if find type method is already defined